# Hibernate not calling UserType for null-value in CriteriaUpdate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-4.x, jpa-2.1

Hibernate uses to classes to represent literals:

- `org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.expression.LiteralExpression`
- `org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.expression.NullLiteralExpression`

The first one will put a placeholder into the query and apply `UserType`s to the value, the second one will simply put `null` into the query, thereby ignoring any configured `UserType`. `CriteriaUpdateImpl` will choose `NullLiteralExpression` if passed a `null` as second parameter to `set(Path<Y>, X)` and `CriteriaBuilderImpl.literal(T)` refuses `null`-values all together.

We use a `UserType` which stores `Calendar`-objects as AES-encrypted date-strings and are forced to replace `null`-values by 0-length data for compatibility reasons.

So the question is whether there is any way to archive the following using only JPA-APIs with a Hibernate-backend, as this is really ugly

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaUpdate<Entity> criteriaUpdate = criteriaBuilder.createCriteriaUpdate(Entity.class);
Root<Entity> root = criteriaUpdate.from(Entity.class);
criteriaUpdate.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("id"), id));
setPathToNull((CriteriaBuilderImpl) criteriaBuilder, criteriaUpdate, root.get("value"));
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaUpdate);
LOG.info("About to perform 2. update");
LOG.info("Updated " + query.executeUpdate() + " entities");
```

Helper:

```
private <Y> CriteriaUpdate<Entity> setPathToNull(CriteriaBuilderImpl criteriaBuilder, CriteriaUpdate<Entity> criteriaUpdate, Path<Y> value) {
    return criteriaUpdate.set(value, new LiteralExpression<>(criteriaBuilder, (Y)null));
}
```

A full working example is provided at
https://github.com/TheConstructor/NullUpdate/tree/master/src/main/java/tc/vom

You may come up with other ways of accessing the property, but the property-name is provided as `String` and the entity can not be loaded beforehand, as this update is part of an reading-value-error-clean-up. If the name of the column would help you, it can be used as well.

Comment: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4776 indicates, that this behavior started in Hibernate 3.5.0

Comment: Created https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9661 to fix this upstream